# big confusion in c pointers

Tags: c

program1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = 65;
    printf("dValueofC:%d,asciiofC:%c,&c:%x\n",c,c,&c);
    int *ptr = NULL;
    printf("ptr:%x,&ptr:%x\n",ptr,&ptr);
    ptr = &c;
    printf("ptr:%x,&ptr:%x,*ptr:%d\n",ptr,&ptr,*ptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

output of program1:

```
    dValueofC:65,asciiofC:A,&c:fffa3fe7
    ptr:0,&ptr:fffa3fe0
    ptr:fffa3fe7,&ptr:fffa3fe0,*ptr:167772225
```

Now pointer points to the address of `c`, but when I dereference it, why it was showing a garbage value instead of 65?

program2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=320;
char *ptr;
ptr=(char *)&a;
printf("%d",*ptr);
return(0);
}
```

output of program2:

```
64
```

From these two programs, I have clearly understood the 2nd program, but I am unable to get a clear understanding of the first one. Could anyone please help me to understand?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: When you dereference `ptr` in the first example (i.e. when you do `*ptr`) you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because `ptr` is a pointer to an `int` but you make it point to a `char`. If you print e.g. `sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(int)` you might get a hint about why.

Comment: Hi Cool, first one it was compiled properly with warning messages.

Comment: @raja: "With warning messages" generally means it did *not* compile "properly".

Comment: @raja ,Now it does,Mat edited it.Also, Use `%p` instead of `%x`.

Comment: Hi Oliver, ptr:fffa3fe7,&ptr:fffa3fe0,*ptr:167772225 this part i did not understand, joachim what ever it be but the pointer points to &c, whenever we are dereference it will fetch value from that address location. what is happening inside stack memory any inputs would be appreciate

Comment: `ptr = &c;` gives undefined behavior as soon as you try to dereference the pointer. Anything can happen, including printing random data, program crashing etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your first program. `char` is 1B type and `int` is probably 4B type (lets assume `int` is 4B for the rest of the answer).

So your memory at `&c` looks like (`65` in decimal = `0x41` in hex):

```
41 00 00 0a .. .. .. ..
^^          first pointer:   &c
^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ second pointer:  ptr
```

That `a0` is some random value (either not initialized memory, some different value on stack, other random memory).

Dereferencing with 1B type (`*&c`) would work perfectly because it reads only one byte.
However with 4B type you load `41 00 00 0a` which gets represented as `0xa000041` on [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machines. And `0xa000041 = 167772225`, thus your "*thrash value*".

---

Second example is basically the same stuff, but the other way around. `320 = 0x140` which gets stored in the memory as (again little endian):

```
40 01 00 00 .. .. .. ..
^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ first pointer:  &a
^^          second pointer: ptr
```

And with `*(char*)` you just take one byte which has value of `0x40 = 64`.

Note that on big endian machine data would be stored as:

```
00 00 01 40 .. .. .. ..
```

And you would get probably zero here.

Comment: is it mean that whenever we declare a char myvar=65, it locates in memory is like any place either LSB or MSB depends on machine type, in my case for example "0x1234568" is address of c, the value of c(65) was presented in at address "68", other memory addresses are filled with some garbage value in stack, so that finally i have fetched all the values presented in memory.

Comment: is my understanding is correct based on your explanation?, much thanks to you Vyktor

Comment: @raja I'm sorry I do not understand the question, please try to rephrase it. But on little endian machines (x86 and x86_64) pointer always points to LSB (the first byte of value) and size of referenced type just says to compiler how many bytes to read from that memory place.

Answer (score 1):

It is not garbage, it is the value of `c` if you view it as an `int`. This happens because `ptr` is declared as a `int*` and not as a `char*`

Answer (score 0):

You should be accessing it as:
For the first Program, Change your last `printf` to

```
 printf("ptr:[%x]\t&ptr:[%x]\t*ptr:[%d]\n",ptr,&ptr, (char)*ptr);
```

Note, `(char)*ptr` at the end.
While doing so, you are reading only first `1 byte`, which is confirmed to hold `65`.

**Output**:

```
Value of C:[65]     ASCII of C:[A]     &c:[bfb381df]
ptr:[0]    &ptr:[bfb381d8]
ptr:[bfb381df]     &ptr:[bfb381d8]   *ptr:[65]
```

Answer (score -1):

Because ptr is an integer pointer, not a char pointer.  Since you have not typecast the contents of *ptr, it expects an integer.  If you want to print out the number stored at &c, use (char)*ptr instead.  Or declare ptr as a char pointer.

Comment: Really?  Just because my answer was a few minutes later, it gets a downvote?